# bash: nano: command not found at Windows git bash

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, nano

I am using git version 2.7.0.windows.1 on a windows pc, I used the following command:

```
$ nano README
```

which results me:

```
bash: nano: command not found
```

Now how can I install nano text editor to git bash?

Comment: how did you get nano on Windows pc ? is it v2.2 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Little modification of the previous solution (@Simopaa) is worked for me on Windows 10 (without Chocolatey):

1. Download [nano-git](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/win32-support/)
2. Move the `nano-git-xxx.exe` to (for example) `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`.
3. Modify the `.gitconfig` file with the following (**single** and **double quotes** are important):

   ```
   [core]
   editor = "winpty '/c/Program Files/Git/bin/nano-git-0d9a7347243.exe'"
   ```
4. (Optional step) Make `nano` available for editing in general:

   Create or edit the one of the startup script of bash (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`) with the followings:

   ```
   export PATH="/c/Program Files/Git/bin:$PATH"
   alias nano="winpty nano"
   ```

Answer (score 8):

If anyone's still struggling with this, here's how I managed to get it working.

1. Download nano-git from https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/win32-support/
2. Move the exe to (for example) `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`. I renamed it to `nano.exe`.
3. Run nano in bash with `winpty nano`
4. Add the following to .gitconfig to make nano your default editor:

`[core]
    editor = winpty C:/Program Files/Git/bin/nano.exe`

There might be a more elegant solution, but this works for me.

Comment: I get errors when I specify `C:/Program Files/Git/bin/nano.exe` (winpty does not like the spaces in the path - even if I surround it with double quotes). I fixed my error by specifying just `nano.exe`, which I installed using Chocolatey with the command `cinst nano`.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have nano install in your system, you just need to add the path of the `exe` file to PATH.

To do it just for Git `bash`, you can open `GITINSTALL_DIR\etc\profile` with any text editor and add this line to it:

```
export PATH="/DriveLetter/PATH/TO/YOUR/NANO:$PATH"
```

Of course you need to change the path above according to your case.

If you havn't installed it yet, just download and put it under `GITINSTALL_DIR\bin` or any folder included in `$PATH`

Comment: The question was how to install it. I presume that the usual way of installing it (I don't know what that is) will put the executable in the default `$PATH`.

Comment: [`nano`](https://www.nano-editor.org/) is a simple editor, designed with [`pico`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_(text_editor)) users in mind.

Answer (score 0):

When you install the new version of git you can choose the editor nano.

Comment: Installing the latest Git and choosing nano as the default editor worked for me when these other solutions did not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download `nano` for Windows
2. Rename the file to `nano.exe`
3. Move it to `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`
4. Open `git` for Windows and issue the following command:

`git config –global core.editor “winpty nano”`