# How to install nano using GitBash in Windows 10?

Tags: github, git-bash

I am trying to install nano editor. From all the previous posts, I am stuck on path. What is path? How do I fix put my path?

I have:

```
$ mv nano ~/path/to/git/share
$ nano abc 
bash: nano: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add it via chocolatey.

```
choco install nano
```

Comment: But to do that, you'll need to install Chocolatey, by running:  `powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))` (or just follow  the Chocolatey installation instructions at https://chocolatey.org/install )

Answer (score 0):

PATH is the environment variable which is used to locate an executable you want to run.

See "[How to permanently set $PATH on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638025/6309)": you can add the folder where nano is in your `.bashrc` (which you can create directly under `%USERPROFILE%`, used by Git bash as `$HOME`)

Add to `~/.bashrc`:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:~/path/to/git/share
```

Then type

```
 source ~/.bashrc
```

---

If you don't want to add it to your PATH, you can follow this [step-by-step procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44066085/6309), which does include the installation of [`nano-git-0d9a7347243.exe`](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/win32-support/).

Comment: Hi, I am using Windows and trying to install nano on Git Bash. I need complete step by step. I am very new here.

Comment: @SimonMatt what posts are you following? Do you have  a link? What version of Git are you using?

Comment: @SimonMatt I have added a link to an even simpler procedure (no PATH modification needed)

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal is to have and use nano on Windows 10, you can [download the nano installer from here](https://github.com/mcandre/nano-win) and just install the .msi file the usual Windows way. No manual path configurations required.